# cx_Oracle 'SELECT INTO' bind variable issue - ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am getting an "illegal variable name" error with the code below.  One is an out parameter, not sure if this syntax works with out parameters, but have also tried a few variations incluing passing a tuple of values in with :1, :2 syntax - that doesn't work either.

```
def no_snapshot_for_day(timestamp):
    # Do we have a snaphot already today
    no_snapshot = True
    snapshot_count = cursor_analytics.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

    sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) INTO :v1 FROM PYTHON_SNAPSHOT WHERE SNAPSHOT_DATE=trunc(:v2) AND SNAPSHOT_STATUS='OK'"

    cursor_analytics.execute(sql,{"v1":snapshot_count, "v2":timestamp})


    if snapshot_count.getvalue() > 0:
        no_snapshot = False

    return no_snapshot
```

Answer (score 1):

'select into' is a PL/SQL SQL syntax.  Technically you can execute

```
sql = "BEGIN SELECT COUNT(1) INTO :v1 FROM PYTHON_SNAPSHOT WHERE SNAPSHOT_DATE=trunc(:v2) AND SNAPSHOT_STATUS='OK'; END;"
```

but in practice, just do a 'select' and then fetch the data, something like this (untested) code:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor_analytics:
    sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) as snapshot_count FROM PYTHON_SNAPSHOT WHERE SNAPSHOT_DATE=trunc(:v2) AND SNAPSHOT_STATUS='OK'"
    cursor_analytics.execute(sql,{"V2": timestamp})
    (snapshot_count,) = cursor_analytics.fetchone()
    print(snapshot_count)
```

Comment: Oh yes, I think I fixed this before just by wrapping begin and end round the SQL

Comment: That is unlikely to be the technically most efficient solution.

Comment: Has to be more efficient than creating a recordset and a fetch

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. With default settings in cx_Oracle 8, for a single row query the 'fetch' is a local call so there is no extra round-trip to the DB.  See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html